# removing the bgcolor and style attribute from html page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a complete html page, but now i have to filter down it to many changes:

First i want to remove all the bgcolor and style attributes from the tables and body tags

i am trying like this:

```
$('#container').find("table").removeAttr("style");
```

this is only removing the style from table but how can i remove from all table, tr, td, th and body tags

any `*` kind of attribute is available for this, which can work for this things,

Comment: Have you tried with CSS?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('#container').find("*").removeAttr("style");
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$("boby,table,tr,td,th").removeAttr("style")
```

Comment: can i add a find to this $('#container').find("boby,table,tr,td,th").removeAttr("style");

Comment: Yes, in `find` you can use the same selectors as in `$()`

Comment: @BenoîtLatinier is it possible to enclose `body` by a `div`?

Comment: In crappy HTML everything is possible... however it is not allowed in specs. If you absolutly want a one-liner you can maybe do this: `$("boby,#container>table,#container>tr,#container>td,#container>th").removeAttr("style")`

Answer (score 0):

You can try for tables:

```
$("table").attr("style"," ");
```

...

Answer (score 0):

`body` inside `div` is invalid. You should enclose all `div` & other elements by `body` tag. You should remove `style` from body separately. Can try using adding all necessary selectors.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').removeAttr('style');
    $('#container').find('div, table, tr, td, th').removeAttr('style');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it this way to ensure everything inside `table` gets selected.

```js
$('#container').find("table").removeAttr('style').find('*').removeAttr('style');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
    </tr>
    <tr style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
      <td style="border: 1px solid black;border-collapse: collapse; color: red;">Text</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```